# How to animate fixed div at certain height of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="fixed">
    fixed
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 body{
        height: 1000px;
    }
    #fixed{
        background-color:yellow;
        width:100%;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        height:50px;
        position : fixed;
    }
```

I want to make the opacity of the div equal 0.1 after it's first scrolled down. 
I've searched for it on the web , but wasn't sure to use css or jquery to accomplish this.

here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/44qEr/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use CSS opacity, you will still need a javascript fallback as support it not there in older version of IE. So I would go with CSS and javascript fallback, or just javascript.

**FULL EDIT**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollYpos = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scrollYpos > 10) {
        $('#fixed').css('opacity', .1);
        $('#fixed').addClass('scrolled');
    } else {
        $('#fixed').css('opacity', 1);
        $('#fixed').removeClass('scrolled');
    }
});
```

Based on your comment add this JS:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.scrolled',function(){
    $('#fixed').toggleClass('hover'); 
   $('#fixed').css('opacity',1);
});
$(document).on('mouseleave','.scrolled',function(){
   $('#fixed').toggleClass('hover'); 
   $('#fixed').css('opacity',.1);
});
```

And this CSS;

```
#fixed.hover {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/XiawICH.png);
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/44qEr/7/

I updated my javascript so the code works when not scrolled. You can't use the hover element. I am sure some jquery pros can simplify my code as I usually don't write things in the shortest method possible.

In order to determine if you are not scrolled, I could have added a `scrollYpos` check in the hover statement which would work as well. Maybe better actually I don't know. However, I think this code is more readable, while may longer.

The code below works without the classes, but can still be a bit buggy at the top if the mouse is over the div when scrolled, I didn't finish it as I think the other way is better.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollYpos = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scrollYpos > 10) {
        $('#fixed').css('opacity', .1);
    } else {
        $('#fixed').css('opacity', 1);
    }
});
$('#fixed').hover(function(){
   var scrollYpos = $(document).scrollTop();
   if(scrollYpos > 0){
       $('#fixed').addClass('hover'); 
       $('#fixed').css('opacity',1);
   } 
}, function(){
  var scrollYpos = $(document).scrollTop();
   if(scrollYpos > 0){
       $('#fixed').removeClass('hover'); 
       $('#fixed').css('opacity',.1);
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/44qEr/8/

Comment: You didn't answer the question.

Comment: I thought the question was: "I've searched for it on the web , but wasn't sure to use css or jquery to accomplish this."

Comment: I'll accept his answer whitin 5 minutes, it says that I can't accept an answer in 5 minutes

Comment: @Leeish I've an additional question, How if I want the word "fixed" 's opacity to be 1 on hover ?  I've tried to add .mouseOver() on the jQuery but it doesnt work.

Comment: If you want the content to be no opaque, you must use a background PNG. The div itself is opaque so any content in it must be opaque. What I would do if you want to get the effect you want is make a tiny semi transparent png and on hover, set the opacity to 1 and the background to the png. Also, instead of using the above code for opacity, just use it to set the background png. However you effect you just stated must be done using both methods as using only the png will result in non-opaque content, just an opaque background.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on @Leeish's answer, it can be nicer to use the `animate` property instead as below:
Additionally, adding the `.stop` property will prevent queued animations from hindering the effect.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollYpos = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scrollYpos > 10) {
        $('#fixed').stop(true);
        $('#fixed').animate({'opacity': .3},500);
    } else {
        $('#fixed').stop(true);
        $('#fixed').animate({'opacity': 1},500);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/44qEr/4/

Comment: That's awesome, thankyou @harryg, but now I've an additional question, how if I want the word "fixed"'s opacity back to 1 on hover, even though it's not on the top of the page. I guess I've to add .mouseOver() function inside the if statement, but it doesnt work so far. A little help maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer to check if the window scroll has changed and set the opacity as required.

```
(function(){
    var $fixed = $('#fixed');
    var $window = $(window);
    var old = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        var _new = $window.scrollTop();
        if (old == 0 && _new > 0){
            $fixed.css({opacity:0.1});
        }
        else if (old > 0 && _new == 0){
            $fixed.css({opacity:1});
        }
        old = _new;
    }, 50);                
})()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/44qEr/2/)

Comment: Apart from if this is right or wrong, wouldn't a timer consume more resources/memory than just putting a listener on the scroll event?